# Using QGIS Server for cascading/proxying an external WMTS service

Tags: wmts, qgis-server, proxy

I have tried to cascade a WMTS service using GeoServer, but it keeps failing since GeoServer does not seem to understand that the WMTS has both EPSG:3857 and EPSG:3006 as available projections. The maps are reprojected and looks far from good. I need my cascaded WMTS to provide tiles in EPSG:3006.

To get around this I am considering to use QGIS Server but I am not sure if that would be possible. Have anyone tried this with success?

Answer (score 1):

[MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/) is the better choice here in any case, as it was designed for this very purpose.

Comment: Thank you Christoph, I'll try MapProxy instead!